# Find path to file after adding it to properties

Tags: c#, image, visual-studio-2013

Trying to find the path to my file after adding it to properties is not working very well. In my properties the file looks like this:

```
internal static System.Drawing.Bitmap one {
        get {
            object obj = ResourceManager.GetObject("one", resourceCulture);
            return ((System.Drawing.Bitmap)(obj));
        }
    }
```

How can I find the path to this file?
And then I try to use it like this:

```
System.Reflection.Assembly thisExe;
        thisExe = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        System.IO.Stream file =
            thisExe.GetManifestResourceStream("WindowsFormsApplication1.Properties.Resources.one");
        this.pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(file);
```

When I run this code:

```
System.Reflection.Assembly thisExe; 
thisExe = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
string [] resources = thisExe.GetManifestResourceNames();
string list = "";

// Build the string of resources.
foreach (string resource in resources)
list += resource + "\r\n";
```

It gives me the following paths: "WFA1.Form1.resources" and "WFA1.Properties.Resources.resources"

Can add that my recourses are embedded.

If you need any more info please let me know.

So what I want is a path to my file, or info on HOW I can find the path. After looking around they say this should work:

```
System.IO.Stream file =
            thisExe.GetManifestResourceStream("[WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1.resources].[a.jpg]");
```

IE:

```
System.IO.Stream file =
            thisExe.GetManifestResourceStream("[Namespace].[file and extension]");
```

So it seems Im getting my namespace wrong cus it still returns null at this line:

```
this.pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(file);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have had a look at this and I don't believe that there's a way to get the path without some serious string building/manipulation. Which of course could lead to bigger issues.

I presume this code will not suffice:

```
var bmp = new Bitmap(WindowsFormsApplication1.Properties.Resources.one);
pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
```

Instead of this one:

```
var thisExe = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
var file = thisExe.GetManifestResourceStream("WindowsFormsApplication1.Properties.Resources.one");
if (file != null) pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(file);
```

**Option 2:**

```
var assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(); 
var stream =  assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("WindowsFormsApplication1.Properties.Resources.one.jpg");
var tempPath = Path.GetTempPath(); 
File.Save(stream, tempPath);
```

Comment: But I dont get it, there must be a way to get the path to my embedded file? seems like it would be something everyone needs

Comment: After compilation the resource files are part of a DLL. So they do not exist anymore in the file system you distribute.

Comment: The only other way would be to save the file/resource to a temp location so you would know exactly where it is.

Comment: I will try the bitmap thing. I just wanted to make a simple picture app, who knew it would be this complicated for such a trivial thing

Comment: at least the picture shows now, the question is will it work on another computer? Will try and let u know

Comment: The picture will definitely show as it will be embedded in the DLL as you have changed the `Build Output` of the images to be `Embedded Resource`. It will work when you redistribute your application.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47908/discussion-between-ique-and-seany84)